# Is it possible to use the conditional arguments in a preseed?

Tags: 12.04, installation, scripts, preseed

I am trying to create a preseed.cfg that is usable for a CD based installation and a network based installation.  I figured the easiest way to do this would be to use a bash conditional "if".  As part of preseed/late I have something similar to the following.

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
if [ -f "/media/cdrom/pool/extras/info.gz" ];\
    then\
        echo "CD Install Info";\ 
        cp /media/cdrom/pool/extras/info.gz /target/var/www/info.gz;\
    else\
        echo "Assuming Network install";\ 
        wget http://192.168.0.1/info.gz;\ 
        cp ./info.gz /target/var/www/info.gz;\
fi
```

Which fails with an error saying that "fi is expected".  I figured this was an issue with the parser so I condensed everything onto one line.

```
if [ -f "media/cdrom/pool/extras/info.gz" ]; cp /media/cdrom/pool/extras/info.gz /target/var/www/info.gz; fi
```

This command finishes without an error, but the file is not copied.  After many attempts using different syntax I began to wonder if this is even possible.  So is it possible to use conditionals (if there are others besides if I should try let me know) during preseed/late?

Comment: er, isn't your one-liner (second option) missing a `then`?

Comment: Your first command *should* work, can you check that you have no trailing whitespace after any of the backslashes (\) ? I was testing it locally and that seemed to be the problem. Admittedly I'm not running this under a preseed environment so YMMV.

Comment: @roadmr Thanks for your quick reply.  A `then` was included in the actual preseed.  Unfortunately, it was trimmed out when I was copying.  Your suggestion to hunt down trailing whitespace may have helped.  I do get a new error, `Unexpected end of file`.  I believe this may be related to the preseed parser not working with the `if` command because everything works as expected if I remove it.  If I chroot and run the the conditional ie: `in-target [ -f "/media/cdrom/pool/extras/info.gz" ];` I get a message saying `'if' No such file or directory`.  Is there another way w/o using if?

Comment: Hi! `if` *should* work, have a look at this fragment, taken verbatim from a preseed I routinely use to install systems. http://paste.ubuntu.com/1692633/ The preseed parser basically passes the entire late_command to a shell (dsh I believe) so I see no reason for it to not work.

Comment: Sorry it looks like the post may have expired.  Would you mind reposting/pasting?

Comment: Sure, here goes: https://gist.github.com/Roadmaster/571a00edfc04123fe52a